# C# Using foreach loop to bulkcopy data to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlbulkcopy

I have a C# console app which reads million source data from a CSV file and inserts them into SQL Server in batches.

I group the data by 1000 count and use foreach to loop the groups. Each loop creates a new `SqlConnection` and a new `SqlBulkCopy` objects and disposes them at the end of the loop.

```
for (int index = 0; index < dts.Count; index++)
{
    DataTable _dt = dts[index];
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conn))
        {
            await connection.OpenAsync();
            //using (SqlTransaction trans = connection.BeginTransaction())
            using (CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
            using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
            {
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "[dbo].[XXXX]";
                bulkCopy.BatchSize = 1000;
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(_dt);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The first 10 groups work fast in 1.x seconds, but after that it takes 4x secs to 60secs every group.

Comment: Can you show the code? it's hard to tell what the problem is from this description

Comment: Are you running the code in Debug mode? The Debugger is notorious for occasionally slowing down `SqlBulkCopy` transactions. But I agree with @Firo, this is difficult to help you with if we can't see some code.

Comment: The SqlBulkCopy has builtin support of batching - see a BatchSize property. 
Example: https://github.com/ycherkes/OrcaSql/blob/0f935baa5990e1948fed2f5451ab388424ab7a83/src/OrcaSql.OSMS/Main.cs#L730

Comment: Could you explain why you need a for loop? Are you reading from multiple files?

Comment: My console app was asked to print message every 2 minutes, and it took more than 20 minutes to import all of all datas once.
I did not notice that there is a SqlBulkCopy.SqlRowsCopied event.

Comment: You can subscribe to SqlRowsCopied event and print the message when event raised.
Also it's better to use the async version of WriteToServer method: WriteToServerAsync

Comment: + I think it's better to use the DataReader instead of pre-filled DataTable just to avoid memory overhead. Something like https://github.com/phatcher/CsvReader (I haven't tested it)

Comment: I forgot to say that when I read csv file, I need to validate data and add additional columns(like create_time) manually

Comment: The CsvReader supports additional columns that don't exist in the source file: https://github.com/phatcher/CsvReader#:~:text=One%20other%20issue%20recently%20arose%20where%20we%20wanted%20to%20use%20SBC%20but%20some%20of%20the%20data%20was%20not%20in%20the%20file%20itself

Comment: Why do create a new connection for each batch? Why don't you reuse the connection?

Comment: I'm afraid that for data validaton you have to implement IDataReader interface and wrap the CsvReader. Similar code: https://github.com/ycherkes/OrcaSql/blob/0f935baa5990e1948fed2f5451ab388424ab7a83/src/OrcaSql.OSMS/TableReader.cs

Comment: Changing the default [`SqlBulkCopyOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopyoptions?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) to the appropriate one for your scenario might result in better performance. (Like using TableLock instead of RowLock)

Comment: I used transaction for each batch, so I create connection each batch

Comment: More Informations, I found the destination table already has 10 billion datas and it has four indexes, does that slow down the performance of bulkcopy?

Comment: correction, 10 million datas

Comment: Of course, clustered indexes significantly affect performance: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/bulk-copy-order-hints?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: I see the class SqlBulkCopyColumnOrderHint is in Microsoft.Data.SqlClient but my console is .net framework 4.8 and I use default System.Data.SqlClient.
Is there same any thing in System.Data.SqlClient?

Comment: The Nuget https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient

Answer (score 0):

> If you use other cores of the processor, you will use a little more speed.
> splitting data by number of cores using threads saves time.

```
 Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Thread1));
  
 Thread t2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Thread2));

    t1.Start();
    t2.Start();
              
   int piece = dts.Count / 2;

   public static void Thread1()
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < piece; index++)
        {
            DataTable _dt = dts[index];
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conn))
                {
                    await connection.OpenAsync();
                    //using (SqlTransaction trans = connection.BeginTransaction())
                    using (CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
                    using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
                    {
                        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "[dbo].[XXXX]";
                        bulkCopy.BatchSize = 1000;
                        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(_dt);
                    }
                }
            }
            }
    }
    public static void Thread2()
    {
        for (int index = piece; index < dts.Count; index++)
        {
            DataTable _dt = dts[index];
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conn))
                {
                    await connection.OpenAsync();
                    //using (SqlTransaction trans = connection.BeginTransaction())
                    using (CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
                    using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
                    {
                        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "[dbo].[XXXX]";
                        bulkCopy.BatchSize = 1000;
                        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(_dt);
                    }
                }
            }
            }
    }
```

> if you just want foreach

```
 foreach(DataTable _dt in dts){
         try
                {
                    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conn))
                    {
                        await connection.OpenAsync();
                        //using (SqlTransaction trans = connection.BeginTransaction())
                        using (CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
                        using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
                        {
                            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "[dbo].[XXXX]";
                            bulkCopy.BatchSize = 1000;
                            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(_dt);
                      }
                  }
             }            
        }
```